# Find files using wild card in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to find files from a directory:

```
String[] search1 = Directory.GetFiles(voiceSource, "85267-*.wav")
                                 .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                 .ToArray();

String[] search2 = Directory.GetFiles(voiceSource, "85267 *.wav")
                                 .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                 .ToArray();
```

But in `search1`, it selects both `85267-s.wav` and `85267 -s.wav`. But I want only `85267-s.wav` to be selected.

`search2` is doing well.

How can I do that?

Comment: use a `'?'`, as the wildcard

Comment: Can you please show me an example?

Comment: @adv12: is it? The `*` comes after the `-` not before.

Comment: Interesting question, if you use `"85267 -*.wav"` then only one file is returned.

Comment: @adv12 is not a regex its a search pattern https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What if you manually search in the explorer for `85267-*.wav` ? Two or one results?

Comment: On command prompt, `>dir 85267-*.wav`  returns both files. Seems like it is broken.

Comment: prefer `Driectory.EnumerateFiles` to `Directory.GetFiles`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SKPaul, how many characters do you expect after `-`, if it is only a single character then you can use `"85267-?.wav"` since that seems to work

Comment: Directory searches match both the long and short names. Use `dir /x` to see the short names. The short name for `85267 -s.wav` is probably `85267-~1.wav`, and it is that short name that is matching.

Comment: Silly Framework, you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is because of short file name. Since you will get `85267-~1.WAV` for  `85267 -s.wav` and since that matches your wild card `"85267-*.wav"` you get both files back.

The is explained in [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Because this method checks against **file names with both the 8.3 file
>   name format and the long file name format**, a search pattern similar
>   to "*1*.txt" may return unexpected file names. For example, using a
>   search pattern of "*1*.txt" will return "longfilename.txt" because the
>   equivalent 8.3 file name format would be "longf~1.txt".

**For workaround** you can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to first select both files matching your criteria and then compare the **actual(long)** file name part using `StartsWith`. Remember [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) does lazy evaluation.

```
String[] search1 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\test", "85267-*.wav")
                         .Where(file => Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith("85267-"))
                         .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                         .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is a side-effect of the MS-Dos 8.3 short name support that's still turned on today on most file systems.  Something you can see with the DIR /X command, it displays those short names.  On my machine:

```
C:\temp>dir /x *.wav

01/21/2015  09:11 AM                 6 85267-~1.WAV 85267 -s.wav
01/21/2015  09:11 AM                 6              85267-s.wav
               2 File(s)             12 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  235,121,160,192 bytes free
```

Note how the short name for "85267 -s" is missing the space.  It is not a valid character in a short name.  What's left over now also matches your wildcard.

That's not where the trouble ends with those short names, A wildcard like `*.wav` will also match a file like `foobar.wavx`, a completely different file type.

Short-name generation is, frankly, a relic from the previous century that ought to be turned off today.  But that is not typically anything you can control yourself.  You have to deal with these accidental matches and double-check what you get back.  With a Regex for example.

Comment: or maybe the framework should let you choose which types of file name you want to search?

Comment: Well, that's not how it is implemented.  The framework just passes the wildcard to the operating system.  Pretty important that it works that way, having the file system driver do the filtering is much faster.

Comment: well, if the file system driver ... wait, I can see where this is headed. I refer myself to your answer.

Comment: Very interesting! I had no idea that MS-Dos short file names are still being used in modern Windows OS's, especially since they're no longer based on DOS.  Is there any plan for Windows to stop that support e.g. Windows 10?

Comment: Telling people that they have to stop using their 20+ year old business critical app, the kind that has no support and no programmer left to modify it, is not a Microsoft strategy.  Very common btw, I've written plenty of it myself and afaik most of it still runs today.